# How do I speed up the execution of my sql query that generates category breadcrumbs for over 458,000 records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I was messing around with the Nested Set Hierarchy Model and have a category table called CategoryNest with the fields CategoryID int identity, CategoryName nvarchar(100), L int, R int, CreatedOn datetime, UpdatedOn datetime.

```
    Note: "Store" is a schema in MS SQL Server.

    SELECT CategoryID,
           node AS CategoryName,
           (
            SELECT
                   '/' + CAST(parent.CategoryID AS nvarchar(max))
            FROM 
                   Store.CategoryNest node,
                   Store.CategoryNest parent
            WHERE
                   node.L BETWEEN parent.L AND parent.R
                   AND node.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
            FOR XML PATH('')
           ) AS BreadcrumbIDs
    FROM
    /* EDIT: this was an unnecessary join.
             Removing it, helped me get results must faster. 
          (
             SELECT
                    node.CategoryID,
                    node.CategoryName node,
                    parent.CategoryName parent
              FROM
                    Store.CategoryNest node,
                    Store.CategoryNest parent
              WHERE 
                    node.L BETWEEN parent.L AND parent.R
          ) AS Category
    */
          Store.CategoryNest Category
    GROUP BY 
          node,
          CategoryID
```

The query works fine and it generates the desired output, but when tested with 458,000 records, it takes over an hour (Note: Query execution was cancelled).

EDIT: After applying my edited query the results were must faster, but I am still open to suggestions for speeding things up further.

```
    Sample results:
    CategoryID CategoryName Breadcrumbs
    1          ROOT         /1
    2          A            /1/2
    3          AA           /1/2/3
    4          AAA          /1/2/3/4
    5          B            /1/5
    6          C            /1/6
    7          CC           /1/6/7
```

I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this query to get the results within seconds NOT hours.

EDIT: No more hours, took care of that, but still open to suggestions for speeding things up.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used the Database Engine Tuning Adviser on it?

Answer (score 1):

Using a sub-query you force the optimizer to use a loop-join. This is very unfortunate for performance.

Reformulate the sub-query (`... '/' + ...`) as a `JOIN`.

This is partially an optimizer, partially an unoptimizable semantic difference.

Comment: It would be great if you included a code example in your comments.